# React JS - confirmation dialog with function callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is what I tried, and details what I want to achieve, can someone help.

```js
class ConfirmDialog extends React.Component {
  callback(action){
   alert(action)
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div className='dialog'>
        <div>confirm dialog</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.callback('yes')}>Yes</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.callback('no')}>No</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
   showDialog: false,
    }
  }
  
  onButtonClick(params) {
 //I want yes no callback here without loosing my previous params
    //so i can use switch case here for yes / no action.
   this.setState({showDialog: !this.state.showDialog})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
 <div>
 <button onClick={() => this.onButtonClick({test: 'test params'})}>
        Click</button>
     {
       this.state.showDialog ? 
      <ConfirmDialog callback={this.onButtonClick}/> : null
     }
 </div>    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.dialog {
  background: tomato;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto; 

}

.dialog button {
  display : inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

> The on callback function should get which action I clicked and without losing the parameters.
>   React JS - confirmation dialog with function callback with the action without loosing the previous parameter

Comment: Check my answer I added and working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/r09z191w3p

Comment: Here you were missing to call props function, instead you called local function.
<button onClick={() => this.callback('yes')}>Yes</button>
 <button onClick={() => this.callback('no')}>No</button>

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing the props correctly to the **ConfigComponent**. You Need to use the class `constructor` and call `super` on the props.

```
class ConfirmDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  callback(action){
    alert(action)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='dialog'>
        <div>confirm dialog</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.callback('yes')}>Yes</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.callback('no')}>No</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And now in your **Hello** component you can work with the value of the callback

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showDialog: false,
    }
  }

  onButtonClick(yesOrNo) {
    //I want yes no callback here without loosing my previous params
    //so i can use switch case here for yes / no action.
    console.log(yesOrNo)
    this.setState({showDialog: !this.state.showDialog})
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={() => this.onButtonClick({test: 'test params'})}>
        Click</button>
     {
       this.state.showDialog ? 
      <ConfirmDialog callback={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}/> : null
     }
    </div>    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here is working example https://codesandbox.io/s/r09z191w3p

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the callback function passed through the components props:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.callback('yes')}>Yes</button>
<button onClick={() => this.props.callback('no')}>No</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function in the props of your ConfirmDialog component

```
<ConfirmDialog callback={this.onSelection}/>
```

and call it when the "yes" or "no" button is clicked

```
this.props.callback(action);
```

You now have your value inside the `onSelection` function.

```js
class ConfirmDialog extends React.Component {
  callback(action){
   this.props.callback(action);
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div className='dialog'>
        <div>confirm dialog</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.callback('yes')}>Yes</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.callback('no')}>No</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     showDialog: false,
    }
  }
  
  onSelection(value) {
    console.log("My dialog value is :", value); //Value contains "yes" or "no"
    //set value to state or use it here
  }
  
  onButtonClick(params) {
   this.setState({showDialog: !this.state.showDialog})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.onButtonClick({test: 'test params'})}>Click</button>
         {
            this.state.showDialog ? 
              <ConfirmDialog callback={this.onSelection}/> 
            : 
              null
         }
      </div>    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.dialog {
  background: tomato;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

.dialog button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: I want callback on onButtonClick funtion without loosibg my previous params ie {test: 'test params'} , check my onClickButton i have added comment in question

Answer (score 0):

In order to better manage your react code, incorporate PropTypes in your code.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

**Add a types for callback:**

```
    ConfirmDialog.propTypes = {
       yesCallback: PropTypes.func,
       noCallback: PropTypes.func
    };
```

**Use the callback in your Confirm Dialog Component**

```
 <button onClick={() => this.props.yesCallback("Yes")}>Yes</button>
 <button onClick={() => this.props.noCallback("No")}>No</button>
```

**Pass props from parent components**

```
<ConfirmDialog
            yesCallback={message => {
              alert(message);
            }}
            noCallback={message => {
              alert(message);
            }}
/>
```

Comment: Hello('Hi', (action) =>{alert(action}).  Function Hello(msg, callbak){callback('yes')}. Like this i want to achieve